# Fields_for not saving data on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for

I'm trying to do the edit action for my users with fields_for.
The problem is it wont save the pro params in User. It wont update the pro attributes.

I have 2 models, `pro` and `user``

User `has_one` pro, and pro `belongs_to` user.

**In the user model**, I've put: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :pro, allow_destroy: true`

**In the users controller, I've put:**

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :pro, :tos_agreement, :avatar,
                                 :avatar_cache, :is_pro,:email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation,
                                 pro_attributes: [
                                   :type, :pro_name, :is_pro, :pro_image,
                                   :is_active, :web, :user_id, :about,
                                   :facebook, :twitter, :linkedin, :telephone])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    pro = @user.build_pro
  end
```

**And finally, in my edit.html.erb view, I've added to the form:**

```
     <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
    <ul class="accordion-submenu">
      <li class="semi_padding">
          <%= f.label :nombre %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true %>
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email %>
          <%= f.label "Algo sobre tí" %>
          <%= f.text_field :description, placeholder: "Soy una persona amante de la decoración..." %>
          <%= f.label "Lugar" %>
          <%= f.text_field :location , placeholder: "¿De donde eres? Ej: Bilbao"%>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-accordion-trigger">
    <i class="icon-switch"> </i> Contraseña</a>
    <ul class="accordion-submenu">
      <li class="semi_padding">
        <%= f.label :contraseña %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %>
        <%= f.label "Confirmación de contraseña" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <% if @user.has_role :pro %>
   <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-accordion-trigger">
    <i class="icon-store"> </i> Datos de marca PRO</a>
    <ul class="accordion-submenu">
      <li class="semi_padding">
       <%= fields_for @user.pro do |builder| %>
        <%= builder.label :facebook %>
        <%= builder.text_field :facebook, placeholder: "Facebook URL" %>
        <%= builder.label :twitter %>
        <%= builder.text_field :twitter,  placeholder: "Twitter URL" %>
        <%= builder.label :linkedin %>
        <%= builder.text_field :linkedin,  placeholder: "Linkedin URL"%>
      <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <% end %>
```

I can see the params are in the logs, but, they don't get saved. Any advice? Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
Started PUT "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-29 19:25:17 +0100
Processing by RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+6D1uzTbQioSLgcxgnMEJOw1ADTgId8LUrCCwiQXpcg=", "user"=>{"avatar_cache"=>"", "name"=>"User 5", "email"=>"prueba5@prueba.com", "description"=>"Et doloremque repudiandae alias odit quis rerum.", "location"=>"Bilbao", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "pro"=>{"facebook"=>"TESTTTTTTT", "twitter"=>"TESTTTTTTT", "linkedin"=>"TESTTTTTTT"}, "commit"=>"Modificar"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Notification Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1 AND "notifications"."viewed_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "notifications"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 30  [["user_id", 6]]
  Notification Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1 AND (viewed_at IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY "notifications"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 30  [["user_id", 6]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```

Comment: Where are you running `@user.update(user_params)`?

Comment: It was missing, I've tried with 
  def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @user.update(user_params)
    pro = @user.build_pro(params[:pro_attributes])
  end ::::: But it wont work

Comment: Your `params` are wrong. You don't have a `pro_attributes` hash inside the `user` hash. There must be a problem with your form. Probably because the `fields_for :pro` should be `fields_for @user.pro`.

Comment: I think you are right. I don't know if my relationship is correct, because @user.pro goes nil. 

I have user has_one :pro, and pro belongs_to user. In the Pro Table I have user_id column. Am I missing something?

Comment: Add `@user.pro.build` to your `edit` action, otherwise it will be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

> pro = @user.build_pro(params[:pro_attributes])

Comment: I've tried with this:


  def update
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @user.update(user_params)
    pro = @user.build_pro(params[:pro_attributes])
  end

But still wont save...

Comment: unfortunately, try also pro.save or update in the end

Comment: Ive added the logs see If you see something ! I can't see anything :(

Comment: i see that the parameters of pro are not inside the user parameters

Comment: Where can the problem be? Maybe in fields_for :pro?

Comment: the correct form is :

`"user"=>{"avatar_cache"=>"", "name"=>"User 5", "pro"=>{"facebook"=>"TESTTTTTTT"... } }`

Comment: Try this : 
'<%= fields_for :pro , @user.pro do |builder| %>'

Comment: Still getting the same:

  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+6D1uzTbQioSLgcxgnMEJOw1ADTgId8LUrCCwiQXpcg=", "user"=>{"avatar_cache"=>"", "name"=>"User 5", "email"=>"prueba5@prueba.com", "description"=>"Et doloremque repudiandae alias odit quis rerum.", "location"=>"Bilbao", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "pro"=>{"facebook"=>"asdasd", "twitter"=>"asdasda", "linkedin"=>"sdasd"}, "commit"=>"Modificar"}

Shouldnt be it pro_attributes? I think

Comment: Good , now try to add the f before fields_for like this :

`<%= **f.**fields_for @user.pro do |builder| %>`

Comment: `<%= f.fields_for @user.pro do |builder| %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change strong params method, you need to pass id's for update

```
params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, :pro, :tos_agreement, :avatar,
                                 :avatar_cache, :is_pro,:email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation,
                                 pro_attributes: [
                                   :user_id, :type, :pro_name, :is_pro, :pro_image,
                                   :is_active, :web, :user_id, :about,
                                   :facebook, :twitter, :linkedin, :telephone])
```

Comment: Ive added the logs see If you see something ! I can't see anything :(

Comment: could you paste the output of "user_params" method?

Comment: "user"=>{"avatar_cache"=>"", "name"=>"User 5", "email"=>"prueba5@prueba.com", "description"=>"Et doloremque repudiandae alias odit quis rerum.", "location"=>"Bilbao", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "pro"=>{"facebook"=>"TESTTTTTTT", "twitter"=>"TESTTTTTTT", "linkedin"=>"TESTTTTTTT"}, "commit"=>"Modificar"}